# PI static LAN IP weird behavior (going to DHCP)

Tags: raspbian, networking, static-ip

After many tries, I decided to simplify my problem.
I am running W10 on my laptop and Raspbian on my PI2, on which is only connected a USB Wifi dongle.
The laptop lan IP is static and set to 192.168.2.1. There is only a direct cable between the laptop and the PI.

To simplify I have:
1. Unpluged the wifi dongle 
2. Set the /etc/network/interfaces file like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

3. Launched on windows "ping 192.168.2.2 -c"
4. Powered on my PI

Here is the result of the ping test:

```
Envoi d'une requête 'Ping'  192.168.2.2 avec 32 octets de données :
Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
Réponse de 192.168.2.1 : Impossible de joindre l'hôte de destination.
Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
Réponse de 192.168.2.2 : octets=32 temps=4 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.2.2 : octets=32 temps=2 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.2.2 : octets=32 temps=2 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.2.2 : octets=32 temps=2 ms TTL=64
Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
```

As you can see, once the PI boots, it sets its IP to the right value, BUT after few seconds, it loses it.
If after few seconds I launch a DHCP server on the computer, the PI gets back its IP from the DHCP.

I have tried to comment the "allow-hotplug eth0" line, but same result.

Any idea how to solve this issue? I don't really understand what is happening (back to dhcp?)/why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently, I tracked it down to TWO dhcpcd clients running on the latest jessie image: dhcpcd5 and isc-dhcp-client. dhcpcd5 does not use /etc/network/interfaces, so if you set a static address there, it will still give you a dhcp address. This address is not visible from 'ifconfig' but can be seen as a secondary address with 'ip addr show'.